# A/B GWO testing pages with dynamic urls and multiple conversion pages

Tags: javascript, google-website-optimizer, ab-testing

I have a site which shows information regarding products. I have dynamic product pages that follow this URL structure: http://www.site.com/product-title/id where id is a product id (if it matters, these urls are actually rewritten urls using apache mod-rewrite).

I have two coldfusion pages templates, product.cfm and the template variation product_v1.cfm and  I want GWO to split our traffic and show users to an alternate page but  mantaining the url (the same url for product.cfm and product_v1.cfm). Also for each test page we have a multiple conversion pages.

summing-up  :

- We have product.cfm and the template variation product_v1.cfm.
- We want, when a given user access to one of the products url domain,  http://www.site.com/product-title/id, mantaining the url gwo shows the original page (generate by product.cfm) or the variation page (generate by product_v1.cfm).
- For each product page we have multiple conversion page that is to say within the product page we have a list of links which point to other pages generate by the convesion page template (conversion_page.cfm)

It is possible to achieve this with GWO?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily, unless you want to use Ajax.  You can do the redirect, no problem, but you're going to get a URL change.  Here are your options:

1. Create a multivariate test (not an AB).
2. Add a page section in the page's head.
3. Create a variation that inserts javascript that will read the current url and redirect to the appropriate one (parsing the current URL).
4. Make sure the tracking code is on both versions of the page.
5. Add the goal tracking to your conversion page (how they get there doesn't matter, only that they get there).

The only way to avoid the URL change (and if you're worried from an SEO standpoint you shouldn't be, but if your customers share your links then it is a problem) you'll have to use some magic.

One option would be to do a URL rewrite based on a parameter added to the URL (close, but not the same URL).

The other option would be to have the javascript in the head simply do an ajax call for the new URL and replace the contents of the entire document with the new one.  Should be straightforward, but I am not the guy to tell you how - no idea.

Comment: Thanks, this is not exactly what i need but the focus the experiment base on multivariate test it's a really good hint!

Answer (score 0):

Multivariate test it is the right type of gwo for this experiment. With A/B Testing  It is not posible to achieve this experimente because I need two different urls . The way to think of this is not in terms of the templates I use server-side, but instead the pages I output to users. So I set up something like this:

- http://www.site.com/product-title/id <- original Product ID built using product.cfm
- http://www.site.com/product-title/id_v1 <- variation for Product ID built using product_v1.cfm

> For each product page we have multiple conversion page that is to say Within the product page we have a list of links which point to other pages generate by the convesion page template (conversion_page.cfm)

I simply add the conversion script to each page.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way, bit dirty one thou. I've stumbled across the same issue as you did, and solved it with creating simple A/B test. At the each variant (expect for the original), I've made just one change - adding small JS snippet for redirect in  tag. Here are the steps:

1. Create normal A/B test
2. Create Variant A
3. Go into UI editor, and in the top left corner you'll find square
   icon which pops up 'Select Elements' modal.
4. There enter 'head', and in the bottom right corner of the modal,
   select 'Add Change -> Javascript'
5. You should have editor in front of you, where you can add snippet:

   ```
   if (document.location.search.indexOf('variant=a') === -1) {
     document.location.href = document.location.href + '?variant=a'
   }
   ```

   This will redirect do the trick with redirecting. You'll need to make this snippet bit more smarter if you'll need to preserve other GET parameters.
6. Make sure you select '*after opening tag*' option.
7. Now, you can go to 'Targeting' tab and set a regex matching for matching dynamic URLs you want to run tests on. In your case that would be '`http://example.com/product-title/([\w-]+)`'.

Tradeoff here is that user will see initial blink. However, you should be able to get use of Google Optimize targeting, objective measuring, analytics and reports.